# how to route traffic on port to ip:port on linux?

Tags: networking, iptables, io-redirection

I'm trying to route all traffic on port `udp 5000` to `udp 192.168.0.1:12333` with the following command:

```
$ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 5000 \
   -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.1:12333
```

It works to some extend (application-specific-ping on that port) but when trying to initiate a connection from outside to inside it just won't connect. like the server is offline.. `Connecting to public_ip:5000.........<forever>`.

The application uses RakNet 2 or 3 to my knowledge. Is there anything I'm missing for full traffic redirect? It does work if I do this:

```
$ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 5000 \
    -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.1:5000
```

But that defeats the purpose of assigning another port.

Comment: Since we are talking about UDP, not TCP, here, what exactly do you mean by "connect"? What are you using to test the DNAT from the outside?

Comment: I am using the `SA-MP Server` software, which uses RakNet for networking. I am connecting from my laptop, to my dedicated host, and the dedicated host should forward my connection to another pc:port (VM) on the local network (which runs the actual game server). By connecting I mean starting the game and seeing the game fails to retrieve any responses / send any data (there are no incomming connection messages on the server). but it is very weird that it's possible to `query` the server and get a response, that works.. (getting amount of players online, server name, ping, etc)

Comment: I see. A lot of opaque custom software here. I guess you have to pull out Wireshark and look at what kinds of packets are getting through and which aren't, and seeing if you can see the difference.

Comment: Is IP forwarding enabled? `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`. Does `192.168.0.1` have a route back to the originating clients via your _redirecting_ machine? If not, you'll probably need to SNAT as well.